# Check the textbox empty or not, if not pass the value in the first form, if not pass to second form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to pass the value to a textbox to form1, so i need to check first whether the form1 is empty or not.

If empty the value go to form1, if not the value will go to form2

I already tried several codes. It doesn't work.

The value didn't go to form2 when the textbox in form1 isn't empty

**mainform**

```
  Dim OpenForm1 As New Form2
  Dim OpenForm2 As New Form4

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(OpenForm1.tbOrderReceived1.Text) Then
        OpenForm1.PassOrderKitchen1 = rbTable1.Text + ":" + cbSpagethi.Text + "-" + tbSpagehti.Text
    ElseIf (OpenForm1.tbOrderReceived1.Text > 0) Then
        OpenForm2.PassOrderKitchen2 = rbTable1.Text + ":" + cbSpagethi.Text + "-" + tbSpagehti.Text
    End If
```

Comment: Define *it dont work.*  Also, you are creating 2 *new* forms, is that what you want or are you trying to pass to an existing form?

Comment: This should work - assuming the `PassOrderKitchen1` and 2 are variables and not a controls. If it is a control with a `.Text` property, you may need to add the `.Text` property to each line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a small change to what you have already coded.  Remove the ElseIf and use Else instead:

```
Dim OpenForm1 As New Form2
Dim OpenForm2 As New Form4

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(OpenForm1.tbOrderReceived1.Text) Then
   OpenForm1.PassOrderKitchen1 = rbTable1.Text + ":" + cbSpagethi.Text + "-" + tbSpagehti.Text
Else
   OpenForm2.PassOrderKitchen2 = rbTable1.Text + ":" + cbSpagethi.Text + "-" + tbSpagehti.Text
End If
```

Comment: @LarsTech They could of course be shown in later code that hasn't been included. :)